# AlphaVantager Time series set YYYY MM DD HH MM SS

Tags: r, time-series, quantmod

I have downloaded data using the `alphavantager` package in R. I am trying to set minute data as a time series `xts` object.

```
rm(list = ls())

library(alphavantager)

AlphaKey <- av_api_key("YOUR API Key (Free) - (obtainable here: https://www.alphavantage.co/support/#api-key)  ")
print(AlphaKey)

args(av_get)

GOOG <- av_get(symbol = "GOOG", av_fun = "TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY", interval = "1min", outputsize = "full")
plot(GOOG$close)   

close_price <- GOOG$close

times <- as.POSIXct(GOOG$timestamp, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
times
times <-format(GOOG$timestamp, format="%H:%M:%S")
df <- cbind(times, close_price)
```

When I run `is.xts(df)`, I get an output `FALSE`. I am trying to set the `GOOG$timestamp` as an xts object with the following format: `YYYY MM DD HH MM SS` so that I can run `chartSeries` from the `quantmod` package.

```
head(GOOG$timestamp)

[1] "2017-10-30 09:30:00 UTC"
[2] "2017-10-30 09:31:00 UTC"
[3] "2017-10-30 09:32:00 UTC"
[4] "2017-10-30 09:33:00 UTC"
[5] "2017-10-30 09:34:00 UTC"
[6] "2017-10-30 09:35:00 UTC"
```

> How can I go about doing this in R?

EDIT: The error I get from the `chartSeries` function:

```
chartSeries(df, TA=NULL)

> Error in try.xts(x, error = "chartSeries requires an xtsible object") : 
  chartSeries requires an xtsible object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `quantmod`, `alphavantager` does not convert data into an `xts` object. Therefore, you must do it yourself. This should work:

```
df <- xts(GOOG[,-1], order.by = as.POSIXct(GOOG$timestamp))
```